# Google maps are not loading

Tags: android, google-maps

### Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
 
       <fragment
           android:id="@+id/map"
           android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

The bottom of the screen is showing a Google logo but no map. How to fix it?

Comment: Check your API Key....

Comment: Your api key may be wrong. Your authentication may be wrong. So just check it.

Comment: What is your minimum SDK version?

Comment: my api key is right and min SDK is 12

Comment: the problem was: the name of the package in manifest was different from the one outside and the one in the google developers console

Answer (score 0):

Replace your fragment with this

```
<fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Comment: But issue is not because of this.

Comment: I also face this problem.My API key correct but map does't load. Then i try with this.

Comment: Its depends on your minimum SDK version. at that time you have used  minimum sdk version below 11